# TensorFlow v2: Replacement for tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

So far, I was using `tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model` to load a `SavedModel` (`tf.estimator` model class). However, this function has unfortunately been removed in TensorFlow v2. So far, in TensorFlow v1, my coding was the following:

```
 predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(model_dir + '/' + model, signature_def_key='predict')

 prediction_feed_dict = dict()

 for key in predict_fn._feed_tensors.keys():

     #forec_data is a DataFrame holding the data to be fed in 
     for index in forec_data.index:
         prediction_feed_dict[key] = [ [ forec_data.loc[index][key] ] ]

 prediction_complete = predict_fn(prediction_feed_dict)
```

Using `tf.saved_model.load`, I unsuccessfully tried the following in TensorFlow v2:

```
 model = tf.saved_model.load(model_dir + '/' + latest_model)
 model_fn = model.signatures['predict']

 prediction_feed_dict = dict()

 for key in model_fn._feed_tensors.keys(): #<-- no replacement for _feed_tensors.keys() found

     #forec_data is a DataFrame holding the data to be fed in 
     for index in forec_data.index:
         prediction_feed_dict[key] = [ [ forec_data.loc[index][key] ] ]

 prediction_complete = model_fn(prediction_feed_dict) #<-- no idea if this is anyhow close to correct
```

So my questions are (both in the context of TensorFlow v2):

1. How can I replace `_feed_tensors.keys()`?
2. How to inference in a straightforward way using a `tf.estimator` model loaded with `tf.saved_model.load`

Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated.

Note: This question is not a duplicate of the one posted [here](http://This%20question%20is%20not%20a%20duplicate%20of%20the%20question%20posted) as the answers provided there all rely on features of TensorFlow v1 that have been removed in TensorFlow v2.

**EDIT:** The question postet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58308258/run-prediction-from-saved-model-in-tensorflow-2-0) seems to ask basically the same thing, but until now (2020-01-22) is also unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have Saved the Estimator Model using the code similar to that mentioned below:

```
input_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x")
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[input_column])

def input_fn():
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    ({"x": [1., 2., 3., 4.]}, [1, 1, 0, 0])).repeat(200).shuffle(64).batch(16)
estimator.train(input_fn)

serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec([input_column]))
export_path = estimator.export_saved_model(
  "/tmp/from_estimator/", serving_input_fn)
```

You can Load the Model using the code mentioned below:

```
imported = tf.saved_model.load(export_path)
```

To **`Predict`** using your Model by passing the Input Features, you can use the below code:

```
def predict(x):
  example = tf.train.Example()
  example.features.feature["x"].float_list.value.extend([x])
  return imported.signatures["predict"](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))

print(predict(1.5))
print(predict(3.5))
```

For more details, please refer [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) in which Saved Models using TF Estimator are explained.