# Simple prediction from frozen .pb saved model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I try for days to use tf exported .pb file model for prediction. The model was generated with bestExporter function as follows :

```
            features_specs = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(serving_features)
        serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec=features_specs,default_batch_size=None)
        exporter[n] = tf.estimator.BestExporter(name="best_exporter", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,event_file_pattern='eval/*.tfevents.*',exports_to_keep=1)
        if train_params["use_early_stop"] == True:
            hookModel[n] = tf.estimator.experimental.stop_if_no_decrease_hook(model[n], metric_name='average_loss', max_steps_without_decrease=train_params["early_stop_max_steps_without_decrease"], min_steps=train_params["early_stop_min_steps"],run_every_secs=train_params["early_stop_run_every_secs"], run_every_steps=train_params["early_stop_run_every_steps"],)
        else:hookModel[n] = None
        train_spec[n] = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn_["train"+m],hooks=[hookModel[n]])
        eval_spec[n] = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn_["test"+m],start_delay_secs = train_params["eval_specs_start_delay_secs"],throttle_secs = train_params["eval_specs_throttle_secs"],exporters=[exporter[n]])
        tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model[n], train_spec[n], eval_spec[n])
```

I think in this way input dict names are referenced...

I successfully load the model with :

```
model_[model_stage+"_"+model_type] = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
```

but i don't know how correctly pass my features dictionnary in the model_XX['prediction'](example) wrapped function.

I saw this topic but didn't help : [TensorFlow v2: Replacement for tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221557/tensorflow-v2-replacement-for-tf-contrib-predictor-from-saved-model)

There's no equivalent of old tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model i used before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to pass a dict in wrapped model. This is a slightly modified synthesis of these given solutions with modifications for TF2-4/Python 3.7 :

- [TensorFlow v2: Replacement for tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221557/tensorflow-v2-replacement-for-tf-contrib-predictor-from-saved-model?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/90440/tensorflow.Example

Second is particulary complete and shows a lot of cases.

So :

```
my_dict = {"feature_1" : str(something), "feature_2" : int(an_int), , "feature_3" : float(a_float), ...}

# Load the model

my_model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)

# Creates a serialized example from dict

    def create_serialized_example(name_to_values):
        example = tf.train.Example()
        for name, values in name_to_values.items():
            feature = example.features.feature[name]
            if isinstance(values, str):
              values = values.encode() # Modified because in new tf versions strings have to be encoded
              add = feature.bytes_list.value.extend
            elif isinstance(values, float):
              add = feature.float_list.value.extend # Modified : float_list instead of float_32 in TF 2
            elif isinstance(values, int):
              add = feature.int64_list.value.extend
            else:
              raise AssertionError('Unsupported type: %s' % type(values[0]))
            add([values]) # Modified : have to be a list, not variable
        return example.SerializeToString()  

# Predict function

pred  = my_model.signatures["predict"] (examples=tf.constant([create_serialized_example(mydict)]))
```